# Adding to site's .htaccessfile to make HTTP site into HTTPS?

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

I own a site which is unsecure, it's just "HTTP". I'm trying to make it "HTTPS".

I'm curious if adding this tidbit of code to my site's .htaccess file will make that change:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://<common_name>%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Well, that "tidbit" may _help_ in the process you are on, but it cannot do _magic_ ... You still need a valid certificate and you still need to setup an https host...

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm confused on what you meant by "may help." -- My question is, can my "tidbit" act alone in doing so or do I need to pursue something like upgrading my host plan with my provider (HostGator)?

Comment: I think I quite definitely answered to that, didnt't I?

Comment: Does `https://your-domain.com/` currently work as expected?

Comment: "adding this tidbit of code" - That bit of code should work for most sites to redirect HTTP to HTTPS (but that alone does not "make a site HTTPS"). However, the code you posted is not necessarily correct, as you are missing the `L` and `R` flags (to create a 301 redirect). And, that code may not work at all, depending on your server config and how the SSL cert is being managed (eg. many sites use a front-end proxy to manage the SSL cert, in which case the above code will not work at all).

Comment: @arkascha, You certainly did. I just was confused on the extent of what "may help" and "cannot do magic" meant. Anyway, after yours, other answers, and further research, I'm going to get a certificate and go about that process. Thanks again! :-)

Comment: That's the right decision you make. Certificates are free these days anyway.